# Cocktails in zero G

Tags: riddle

People might think that I am where you buy cocktails in zero G.
But, I have been there 28 times while writing this and I am not drunk.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The spacebar

Because:

> You buy cocktails in a bar, zero G is in space and there are 28 spaces in the sentence if you include the two spaces at the end of the first line (open the edit-screen of the question to see for yourself).

Comment: may be @michael refers to the number of times our his hand reached out for the space bar, so 26 are the number of spaces in between the words + space bar pressed twice to advance to new line

Comment: Good job, Jordy.  Please remove the spoilers from the comments, thanks.